# What is RFC-compliant URI

Tags: .net, uri, rfc, rfc2396, .net-4.5

While going through features of [.NET framework 4.5, I found that it supports RFC-compliant URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/index#networking-3). What does it mean to have RFC-compliant URI support?

Comment: I assume you read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=VS.110).aspx). Digging into [System.Net.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=VS.110).aspx) indicates that several new classes are designed to match RFC2616, but no further information that I can find.

Comment: @Damin: yes.. you are right..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RFC is a set of internet standards that define various aspects of internet protocols - in your case the standard format of an URI. You can find the relevant standard here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

RFC 2396 defines explicitly what are the parts that make up an URI (for example the scheme, authority, path etc.) and what are the valid values for each of them.

What they mean with RFC-compliant URIs is that the Uri class from the .NET framework follows the above standard and enforces it.

Comment: Defiintely take a look at RFC 3986, like @Quentin mentioned.

Comment: Especially since 3986 makes 2396 obsolete, you should actually only look at 3986 :-) http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 2):

An RFC is a specification; an RFC compliant URI is one which conforms to that specification.

You didn't say *which* RFC though, it might mean [3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) or [2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (or one I haven't spotted).